# fill second primefaces selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf-2

I have two selectOneMenu. I choose item from selectOneMenu1 and I add item value to where condition for query. Query result is successful. But I didn't put query result to selectOneMenu2. selectOneMenu2 is empty everytime. I add managedBean and xhtml page code about this issue.

// BirimManagedBean about above issue

```
@Override
public void processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
    String birimRequested = deger;
    byte birimId = Byte.parseByte(
    bolumManagedBean.bolumBilgileriniGetir(birimId);
}
```

// BolumManagedBean about above issue

```
public void bolumBilgileriniGetir(byte id) {
    bolumler = new ArrayList<Bolum>();
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    Query query = session.createQuery("from Bolum b where b.birim.birim_id = :id");
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    bolumler = query.list();
```

}

// yeni_kayit.xhtml about above issue

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="birimi" value="#{birimMBean.deger}" style="float: left;" >
                <f:selectItems value="#{birimMBean.birimler}" var="birim" itemLabel="#{birim.birim_adi}" itemValue="#{birim.birim_id}" />
                <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{birimMBean.processAjaxBehavior}" />        
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <br/><br/>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="bolumu" value="#{bolumMBean.secilenBolum}" style="float: left;">
                <f:selectItems value="#{bolumMBean.bolumler}" var="bolum" itemLabel="#{bolum.bolum_adi}" itemValue="#{bolum.bolum_id}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: add `update="bolumu"` to the `p:ajax` tag and give it another try please.

Comment: Thanks for this answer :) I solved my problem with this answer.

Comment: no problem. i added it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `update="bolumu"` to the `p:ajax` tag.